# In ImageJ, how to set pixel value to zero for any pixel intensity greater than some arbitrary value in the whole image?

Tags: image-processing, pixel, subtraction, imagej, threshold

I have Z-stacks of fluorescently labelled cells.

The samples have an artefact that causes very bright regions inside the cells which are not based on my signal of interest.

Since the intensity (brightness) of these artefacts is far above my signal of interest's intensity, I want to simply zero all those pixels that are above some arbitrary value I will chose.

So I want  macro that logically does something like:

For each slice:

For each pixel:

```
 if pixel intensity>150 then set pixel=0
```

I am coding in imageJ macro language. I want to avoid using ROIs for this part because I already have ROIs representing each cell and am looping through them in my script.

I think this should be really simple but right now my attempted solution is super cumbersome; going through thresholding, analyze particles, generating ROIs, selecting each ROI, and subtracting the value (e.g 150) from each ROI.

Any idea how this is done in simple way?

Comment: You can do this by looping over every pixel (three nested for-loops: outer one is the slice, next is x, final one y) and have `if(getPixel(x, y) > 150) setPixel(x, y, 0);` This would be easy to understand and debug, but it will be slow.An alternative solution would be to threshold each slice using the range 0,150 and then use image calculator with the AND function to get the result.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is resolved using selection and thresholding:

`HotPix = 150; Stack.getStatistics(voxelCount, mean, min, StackMax, stdDev); setThreshold(HotPix, StackMax); //your thresholds here for (i = 1; i <= nSlices; i++) { setSlice(i); run("Create Selection"); if (selectionType() != -1) { run("Set...", "value=0"); } run("Select None"); } resetThreshold;`

the olsution comes from @antonis on imageJ forum: https://forum.image.sc/t/how-to-delete-all-pixels-or-set-to-zero-in-a-roi-which-are-above-a-certain-value/51173/5